# how to switch from one datagrid to another grid in flex 4.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to switch from one datagrid to another datagrid on the single click of a button.
Please provide solution.

these are my two datagrids.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg_class" x="0" y="0" ..>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg" x="0" y="0" ..>
```

Comment: <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg_class" x="0" y="0" ..>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="dg" x="0" y="0" ..>

my data grids....

Comment: What do you mean by "switch" ?

Comment: one of my grid is displayed at a time. now i want that when i click on a button another grid will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understood correctly but let´s try

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleGrids);

function toggleGrids(e:MouseEvent):void{
      dg_class.visible = !dg_class.visible;
      dg.visible = !dg_class.visible;
}
```

Comment: no its not working.... what actually i need to do is currently my "dg" grid is displaying. now when  i click on display button "Dg_class" grikd should appear.

Comment: I just built a small fla and tested it. And it works fine here. You press the button, one appears and the other disappears.